# TPS for one gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How many transactions per second can one wso2-gateway manage in a distributed setup? WSO2 says on their website that wso2 api manager "Supports up to 1300 TPS on a single node". But what about a distributed setup, is the number still 1300 per gateway?